# CSS 3 items vertically aligned {left, center, right} floating

Tags: css

here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/67/

I need to place the 3 items (text and 2 images), vertically aligned (it's ok) but the right picture should be anchored on right, and the text centered

Good CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPAN tags are as wide as their CONTENTS, so setting something to be centered doesn't make any sense.

Use a DIV (a block element) instead. Block elements are as wide as their CONTAINERS.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">  Lorem </div>
```

One good trick, add a background-color or border to the element do you can see exactly where it is in the layout. This is very hand in debugging these types of issues.

```
<div style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #ff0000">  Lorem </div>
```

Comment: thanks if you see http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/72/, and widden the html, is it possible to make sure the right pic stays anchored on the right,  may not be possible as the elts are relatively positioned

Comment: Time to do a bit of homework: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Comment: thanks for the homework, I just dislike CSS , it's working like this http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/73/ working, wait I will see who deserve the answer

Answer (score 1):

you don't need all that fancy css-rules and wrapper-elements, a simple `vertical-align` is enough. [(see here)](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/2bNsC/70/).

As spans are inline-elements, it collapses to fit the content and therefore the text can't be centered. YOu cant use a block-level element either, this would break your layout.

You either need to apply `display:inline-block;` and add a `width` or use floats for your layout.

Comment: thanks for simplifying the things, how can I make sure the right picture stays on the right- the text fits in the space between, and all elts are centered vertically a little like this http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/71/ but it's dirty